# How to group and add a count attribute to a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [{"foo": "a", "bar": "1", "baz": "A_CODE"}, 
        {"foo": "a", "bar": "12", "baz": "A_CODE"}, 
        {"foo": "b", "bar": "2", "baz": "ANOTHER_CODE"}]
```

What is the most elegant way to obtain the following by grouping the dictionaries based on `baz`? `bar` can be omitted.

```
items = [{"foo": "a", "baz": "A_CODE", "count": 2},  
        {"foo": "b", "baz": "ANOTHER_CODE", "count": 1}]
```

Here is how I am doing it now:

```
items = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(list, lambda item: item["baz"]):
    item["count"] = sum([1 for item in group])
    items.append(item)
```

Comment: What happened to the `bar` keys? By what criteria are the dictionaries grouped? Are the dictionaries sorted by their selection criteria?

Comment: Please see the edit. Sorry for the indentation.

Comment: I still don't see what happend to bar

Comment: So what about the `bar` key? And what about order, is the input list always sorted by `baz`? And have you made any attempts yourself yet?

Comment: The list is not sorted. Please see the edits I made. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt provide much information, May this help you to work out.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in list:
    d[i["baz"]]+=1
>>[{"baz":i, "count":j} for i,j in d.items()]
 [{'baz': 'A_CODE', 'count': 2}, {'baz': 'ANOTHER_CODE', 'count': 1}]
```

Comment: I didn't know about `defaultdict`, thank you. Do you think it is better than the way I did it with `groupby`?

Comment: @mickael: `groupby` requires that the input is sorted. Which is why I asked about the input being sorted on the selection key; having to sort first makes `groupby` a poorer choice in that case.